# Is there something like "PageRank" in solr?

Tags: java, search, solr

I know that Google sorts the searching results based on importance of a page(PageRank) and the revelance of a page to the query(something like td-idf).
And I also found that solr's score formula is:

> score(q,d)   =   coord(q,d)  ·  queryNorm(q)  ·   ∑   ( tf(t in d)  ·  idf(t)2  ·  t.getBoost() ·  norm(t,d) )

So i wonder whether there is something like "PageRank" working in solr?
If there is, how can i make the configuration?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't, so you can't configure Solr to use it for scoring, but you can implement it yourself and index it as a factor in your documents. Solr has no concept of links between documents for scoring.

Depending on how you're indexing the documents, the application might already have functionality for using a PageRank-ish algorithm (Nutch has this at least).